# How to Specify filepath but not name InDesign applescript

Tags: applescript, automator, adobe-indesign

I am new to applescript.
I am trying to create an Automator script app that opens a batch existing files in InDesign, finds and changes text within the file. ( I thought this would be the complicated bit but it's not it was easy)
What I'm struggling with is then saving these files in another location but using the original filenames as I need to keep the original files.
I have a script to specify a path and a filename but I need to specify the path only and use the existing filename. Is this possible?

The code I tried was this:

```
tell application "Adobe InDesign CS5.5"
save document 1 to "users:xxx:Desktop:"
close document 1
end tell
```

It doesn't seem to work for the reason that I'm not specifying a filename BUT I DON'T WANT TO! Is there a way of calling up the original filename?
I'm assuming there must be a way of doing this, as I can't see the point of a script that is specific to one particular file.

My next step is to then rename the files by replacing the last bit of the filename eg:
xxx_xxx_M6.indd to xxx_xxx_M7.indd
I know how to do this in another script but if it can be done in the above section that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the original file name when saving, you can just pull it from the file's properties and combine it with the path you want to save to, like so:

```
set origName to the name of document 1 as string
save document 1 to ("your:path:here:" & origName)
```

EDIT: If you already have your own routine for replacing the suffix, you can just perform those operations on `origName` before you pass it to the save command. I'll leave my look at suffix replacement below just in case it's helpful to anyone.

---

As for the second part of your question, about replacing a suffix, it depends on what exactly you want to do. From your example I’m guessing you want to increment a number, which you could do with the following code:

```
set thePoint to the offset of "." in origName
set firstPart to (characters 1 through (thePoint - 1) of origName) as string
set fpLength to the length of firstPart

set newSuffix to ((the last character of firstPart) as number) + 1
set newName to (characters 1 through (fpLength - 1) of firstPart) & newSuffix ¬
    & ".indd" as string
```

This takes separates the file’s name from its extension, creates a new suffix by incrementing the last character (coerced to a number) of that name by 1, and then combines the lot to form a full file name that you can then use in the save command.

The key is breaking apart the original file name, then performing operations on the parts.

Now, this currently has a few limitations: any suffix other than a single digit makes things more complicated (though not impossible), and assumes that anyone running the script has “Show all filename extensions” enabled in the Finder’s preferences (this can be worked around, though).

Wrapping everything up gives us this:

```
tell application "Adobe InDesign CS5.5"
    set origName to the name of document 1 as string

    set thePoint to the offset of "." in origName
    set firstPart to (characters 1 through (thePoint - 1) of origName) as string
    set fpLength to the length of firstPart

    set newSuffix to ((the last character of firstPart) as number) + 1
    set newName to (characters 1 through (fpLength - 1) of firstPart) ¬
        & newSuffix & ".indd" as string

    save document 1 to ("your:path:here:" & newName)
end tell
```

If you could provide some more information about the suffixes you’d intend to use I’d be happy to update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

InDesign documents have 3 properties that could interests you:
`name` : "xxx_xxx_M6.indd"
`file path` : file "Macintosh HD:sourceFolder:"
`full name` : file "Macintosh HD:sourceFolder:xxx_xxx_M6.indd"

So, to save (& close) the open file on the desktop, with same name, you could do this :

```
tell application "Adobe InDesign CS5.5"  
    save document 1 to "users:xxx:Desktop:" & name of document 1  
    close document 1  
end tell
```